# authorize.net Java SDK 1.8.6 concurrency, not working?

Tags: java, authorize.net

Authorize.net sample code of Java SDK 1.8.6

//Common code to set for all requests

```
   ApiOperationBase.setEnvironment(Environment.SANDBOX);
MerchantAuthenticationType merchantAuthenticationType  = new MerchantAuthenticationType() ;
merchantAuthenticationType.setName(“YOUR_API_LOGIN_ID”);
merchantAuthenticationType.setTransactionKey(“YOUR_TRANSACTION_KEY”);
ApiOperationBase.setMerchantAuthentication(merchantAuthenticationType);
```

It uses the static method ApiOperationBase.setMerchantAuthentication. For a platform with multiple merchants, uses can not pay to different merchants at the time.

For SDK version 1.8.3,

```
Merchant merchant = Merchant.createMerchant(Environment.SANDBOX, apiLoginId, transactionKey);
```

It works for concurrency.

Can any one explain the API for 1.8.6 in case of concurrency? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From glancing through the source code, it looks like this is still possible. You just need to use other methods instead of the static operations on `ApiOperationsBase`.

For the environment, call `controller.execute(environment)` instead of `controller.execute()`.

For the merchant authentication, call `apiRequest.setMerchantAuthentication(merchantAuthenticationType)`.

I haven't tested this out, exactly, but I'm pretty sure this works.